# C++ BOOL FUNCTION WITH * , could you help me? What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++

Question:
Consider a structure to represent a point in 2D space and implement a
function that indicates whether a given point p is located inside or outside a rectangle.
The rectangle is defined by its lower left v1 and upper right v2 vertices. THE
function must return true if the point is located inside the rectangle, and
false otherwise. This function must obey the following prototype:
bool dentroRetangulo(Ponto* v1, Ponto* v2, Ponto* P);

My code:

```
using namespace std;

struct Ponto{
    int x;
    int y;
};

bool dentroRetangulo(Ponto* v1, Ponto* v2, Ponto* P){
    if ((P.x>=v1.x && P.x<=v2.x)&&(P.y>=v1.y && P.y<=v2.y))
        return true;
    
    return false;
}

int main(){

    Ponto v1,v2,P;
    //int x, y;

    cout << "Insert the X and Y from the vertex of the lower left rectangle: \n";
    cout << "X = ";
    cin >> v1.x;
    cout << "Y = ";
    cin >> v1.y;
    cout << "Insert the X and Y from the vertex of the upper right rectangle: \n";
    cout << "X = ";
    cin >> v2.x;
    cout << "Y = ";
    cin >> v2.y;

    cout << "The coordinates of the rectangle vertices are: "<<"("<<v1.x <<"," <<v1.y<<")"<<"(" <<v2.x<<","<< v2.y<<")"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nEnter the position of the point"<<endl;
    cout<<"X = ";
    cin>>P.x;
    cout<<"Y = ";
    cin>>P.y;

    if (dentroRetangulo(v1, v2, P){}  // Here I am not able to call the function correctly due to the pointer
        cout<<"\nThis Point is inside the Rectangle !"<<endl;
        cout<<"("<<P.x<<")"<<" "<<"("<<P.y<<")"<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"This point is outside the rectangle !"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to make the code compile? I don't see how it would since `dentroRectangulo` takes in a pointer, which you haven't provided, not to mention the syntax for their usage in the actual function uses the `.` operator, which it needs to be using the `->` operator instead (or `*P.x`)

Comment: The main question is what wrong with your question. At least you should provide error description. Hint for you, `Ponto*` is pointer, and pointer (eg address of object) has to be passed as parameter

Comment: Are you getting compilation error or what? Because those {} after function call must not be there.

Comment: OT: The real "bug" is the proto-type of the function. Using pointer parameters for this function is simply wrong. The function should take references (or plain structs). Further, things should be `const`

Comment: Sorry, it was just not to have my code copied. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the signature `bool dentroRetangulo(Ponto* v1, Ponto* v2, Ponto* P)`, you have 3 pointer arguments. So you need to use `->` to access the data member.

To pass pointer arguments, you need to use `&`.

The compile error message from modern compiler is very clear, just follow them and fix your code.

```cpp
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

struct Ponto {
  int x;
  int y;
};

bool dentroRetangulo(Ponto* v1, Ponto* v2, Ponto* P) {
  if ((P->x >= v1->x && P->x <= v2->x) && (P->y >= v1->y && P->y <= v2->y))
    return true;

  return false;
}

int main() {
  Ponto v1, v2, P;
  // int x, y;

  cout << "Insert the X and Y from the vertex of the lower left rectangle: \n";
  cout << "X = ";
  cin >> v1.x;
  cout << "Y = ";
  cin >> v1.y;
  cout << "Insert the X and Y from the vertex of the upper right rectangle: \n";
  cout << "X = ";
  cin >> v2.x;
  cout << "Y = ";
  cin >> v2.y;

  cout << "The coordinates of the rectangle vertices are: "
       << "(" << v1.x << "," << v1.y << ")"
       << "(" << v2.x << "," << v2.y << ")" << endl;
  cout << "\nEnter the position of the point" << endl;
  cout << "X = ";
  cin >> P.x;
  cout << "Y = ";
  cin >> P.y;

  if (dentroRetangulo(&v1, &v2, &P)) {  // Here I am not able to call the
                    // function correctly due to the pointer
    cout << "\nThis Point is inside the Rectangle !" << endl;
    cout << "(" << P.x << ")"
     << " "
     << "(" << P.y << ")" << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "This point is outside the rectangle !" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Online [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cxhve9dfd).

Comment: @Bruno If this answer helped you, don't forget to accept and upvote...